# In Racket or Scheme, is there any way to convert an ellipsis syntax object to a list of syntax objects?

Tags: scheme, pattern-matching, racket, ellipsis, syntax-object

For example:

```
(syntax-case #'(a b c d) ()
  ((x ...) (list #'x ...))
```

In the example, `(list #'x ...)` obviously does not work, but what can I do to output the equivalent of `(list #'a #'b #'c #'d)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
Welcome to Racket v5.90.0.6.
-> (syntax-case #'(a b c d) ()
     ((x ...) (syntax->list #'(x ...))))
'(#<syntax:5:16 a> #<syntax:5:18 b> #<syntax:5:20 c> #<syntax:5:22 d>)
```

For more, see the [syntax object operations](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/reference/stxops.html) section and the functions exported by [`syntax/stx`](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/syntax/syntax-helpers.html).